# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, jpa-2.0

I get this exception but I can not figure out what is wrong with my configuration
I am posting the relevent files thanks for any help
I am using 
Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE
hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.10.Final (Should work with JPA 2)

Trying to run the code from a JUnit file

```
package com.successcharging.core.dao.jpa;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.successcharging.core.security.dao.UserDao;
import com.successcharging.core.security.model.User;
import com.successcharging.core.security.model.UserImp;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:applicationContext/applicationContext*.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImplTest {

private static final boolean ENABLED = true;

private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

private static final String USERNAME = "joe.bloggs";

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
private User user;
@Before
public void before() {
    user = new UserImp();
    user.setName(USERNAME);
    user.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    user.setEnabled(ENABLED);

    userDao.save(user);
}

@Test
public void findByUserName() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(user);
    User user2 = userDao.findById(user.getId());

    Assert.assertNotNull(user2);
    Assert.assertEquals(USERNAME, user2.getName());
}
}
```

#### applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.successcharging.core" />
</beans>
```

#### applicationContext-persistence.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.successcharging.core" />

    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="successcharging.core.security" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" />
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.129:3306/SC_SECURITY" />
    <property name="username" value="sc_admin" />
    <property name="password" value="123" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

#### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="successcharging.core.security"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true 1, false 0" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I found the problem I had to add the datasource to the persistenceUnitManager
something like this
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
   <bean   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>
    </property>

Comment: Put this as an answer and accept it; that is easier for other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

I found the problem I had to add the datasource to the persistenceUnitManager something like this

```xml
<property name="persistenceUnitManager">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManag‌​er">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing similar issue but was not using datasource in my case issue got resolved by adding hibernate key while providing database details in my persistence.xml file. Note that Hibernate 3.x and 4.x have different syntax as mentioned below (hit this while downgrading Hibernate 4.x to 3.x).

Changed below (Hibernate 4.x syntax) :

```
<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="..."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="..."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="..."/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..."/>
 </properties>
```

With (Hibernate 3.x syntax) :

```
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="..."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="..."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="..."/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="..."/>
  </properties>
```